# Generate ID card through fpdf, php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

I want to generate ID card for the students admitted in the college.

i have linked a photo in which i am sharing as to how the i want the id cards in pdf file through php and fdpf. and i am fetching the date from mysql.

[image]

Suppose i have 13 students available for a particular course. Now, i want the data to first actually work multicolumn wise and then as the page is filled, it should create the back side of the page in next page and move on to other page. On one A4 page, i can have only six ID cards and on the next page, six backside of those id card and again this step should repeat. I am confused.

Comment: This sort of thing wouldn't usually be handled with low-level libraries such as FPDF; it is much more suited to a reporting style solution, such as Crystal Reports or Jasper Server. That said, you _can_ use FPDF; do you have some code you can edit into your question, so we can guide you? It is (nearly!) a pre-requisite here.

Comment: Hmmm i guess I will have to do that only. I will try and write the code within a day :). I am new to programming.

Comment: Great. Remember it doesn't have to _work_ to ask a question here, but a start will give people a real insight into the nature of the problem, and how you are tackling it. Good luck!

Comment: Your strategy could be to work out how many cards will fit on a page, and then generate PDF pages on an alternate basis - render all the fronts, up to either the maximum on the page, or the end of the student list for the class. Then, for the reverse side, render all the matching data using a copy of the same loop. You'll need to find commands in FPDF to force a new page for this project - see the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use the [AddPage()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/addpage.htm) method to simulate a page feed. To add two pages, call it twice.
- There's a third-party script to [use a different margin for odd and even pages, like in a book](http://fpdf.org/en/script/script86.php), but I don't know if you can force double-sided printing from a PDF document.

Comment: I know but can i actually add two pages ? As in one with the back side and another page will be having the id of other student. looping as in.

Comment: I've edited my answer but I'm no longer sure if your doubt is about FPDF or about algorithms...

Comment: I guess I will look at the third party script :). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

when you are trying to generate ID then what should your goal is to generate six on a page and you can do that with looping.

Because printing on backside is printer property.

Comment: Hmm this is not the answer i am looking for. What i am saying is, I need to have those backside items to be there on the next page after the id cards depending on the number of ids it has generated.

Comment: for adding more page when six items generate.as i done this with using fpdf in that there is a function for adding more pages.check your pdf class it must have that function.